# How to secure spring-boot rest api that is used by angular front end that doesn't need user to login?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have spring-boot REST API that I want to be securely accessed by three applications:

1. An Angular front end application that doesn't need login to use that application (I do not want users to login)
2. Another Angular application that requires user to login using application's own login page
3. Other REST API service (deployed separately by third party) that would consume spring-boot REST API

Currently looking at KeyCloak server to manage authentication & authorization flows. So far I understand that these are good for browser based applications that requires user to login (scenario #2 above).

Don't know how easy and flexible KeyCloak server login page customization is (so far I hear it's bit complicated)

Is there a single OpenId / OAuth2 server solution that would take care of all 3 scenarios above? Any links to specific how to's would help too.

I tried google and stackoverflow searches but either I am not doing correct search phrases or there's isn't any article / post that I see address all these scenarios.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What you mean by "securely accessed", against Point-1?

Comment: #1 is through browser app. I want only that particular browser app to be able to access the REST APIs.  #2 For #2 browser app, only when user credentials are validated, should be able to access REST APIs.